# How do I transform a database table into a "pivot" DataTable?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq, datatable

I have data that looks like these, example:

```
 | MemberID | Username | QuestionID |     Question     | Answer | 
 |----------|----------|------------|------------------|--------|
 |    58    |   John   |     1      | Recommend This?  |  Yes   |
 |    58    |   John   |     2      | How much rating? |  10    |
 |    59    |   Zess   |     1      | Recommend This?  |  No    |
 |    59    |   Zess   |     2      | How much rating? |  8     |
```

Have a class like this (pls ignore some of the fields):

```
 class reportlist
    {
        public string MemberID { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }
        public DateTime Submitted_On { get; set; }
        public int TotalPoint { get; set; }
    }
```

And have a mysql reader to add data to the reportlist:

```
 while (reader.Read())
 {
       reportlist.Add(new reportlist() { MemberID = reader["MemberID"].ToString(), Username = reader["Username"].ToString(),
                        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(), Email = reader["Email"].ToString(), QuestionID = int.Parse(reader["QuestionID"].ToString()), Question = reader["Question"].ToString(),
                        Answer = reader["Answer"].ToString(), Submitted_On = DateTime.Parse(reader["CreationDate"].ToString()), TotalPoint = int.Parse(reader["TotalPoint"].ToString()) });                        
 }
```

Now is where i am stuck, I tried using Linq to query:

```
var groupedList = reportlist
           .GroupBy(u => u.QuestionID, u => u.MemberID)
           .ToList();

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (var group in groupedList)
{
   //add columns, rows to datatable, stuck here
}
```

and not sure how to obtain these result into the datatable. Basically, I want to group up the question and let it become columns, and add all the data to datatable to form these result (example):

```
 | MemberID | Username | Recommend This? | How much rating? | 
 | 58       |   John   |      Yes        |       10         | 
 | 59       |   Zess   |      No         |        8         |
```

Please guide on how to obtain the result or better solution? I am stuck for quite some time since I am not good in linq. I did tried to search around, yield not much result, maybe doesn't quite understand how it work.

side info: the final datatable is used for EPPlus library (to generate excel spreadsheet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the code you posted in your question cannot be your real code, given that it features the following, that would never compile:

```
 class reportlist { ... }
 reportlist.Add(new reportlist() { ... });
```

Making some assumptions to be able to answer the question:

```
List<reportlist> list; // the list filled by the data reader.
```

You can make a "pivot table" (i.e. convert row values to columns) in a few steps:

```
// Get unique question info.
var questions = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.QuestionID)
    .Select(x => new { Id = x.Key, Title = x.First().Question });

// Set up the columns for the data table as a "pivot table" with columns per question.
DataTable myTable = new DataTable("QuestionsPivotTable");
var fixedColumns = new [] { 
    new DataColumn("Member ID", typeof(string)),
    new DataColumn("User Name", typeof(string)),
};
var questionColumns = questions.Select(x => new DataColumn(x.Title, typeof(string)));
myTable.Columns.AddRange(fixedColumns.Concat(questionColumns).ToArray());
```

With the data table setup including the "pivot" question columns, we can get a row for each member as an array of values:

```
// Get the column values for each member as an array.
var rows = list
    .GroupBy(x => x.MemberID)
    .Select(x => {
        var memberCols = new object[] { x.Key, x.First().Username };
        var answerCols = questions.Select(q => x.Where(a => a.QuestionID == q.Id).Select(a => a.Answer).FirstOrDefault());
        return memberCols.Concat(answerCols).ToArray();
    });
```

Now it is easy to fill the table:

```
// Fill the table.
foreach (var memberRow in rows)
{
    var row = myTable.NewRow().ItemArray = memberRow;
    myTable.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Where, using your example data, the code below:

```
// Show the output
for (var i = 0; i < myTable.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    Console.Write("{0}, ", myTable.Columns[i]);
Console.WriteLine("{0}", myTable.Columns[myTable.Columns.Count - 1]);
foreach (var row in myTable.AsEnumerable())
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", row.ItemArray.Select(x => x == null ? "<null>" : x.ToString())));
```

Produces this output:

```
Member ID, User Name, Recommend This?, How much rating?
58, John, Yes, 10
59, Zess, No, 8
```

Comment: appreciate for your explanation and code. Thanks! 
Already go through it and able to solve my problem. Definitely will study it and apply it for upcoming work~